# nohup and enter will stop the process: why?

Tags: bash, process, terminal, nohup

My script needs root privileges and I want to run it on a remote machine and then be able to turn off my local computer.

So I did:
$ nohup sudo ./myScript arg1 &

... which I always do, but on a different machine where I'm always root, so without `sudo`. For some reason now it's not working:

```
nohup sudo ./myScript.sh 1 &  //then I press enter twice
[8] 24264
me@my-laptop:~/myFolder$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'


[8]+  Stopped                 nohup sudo ./myScript.sh 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sudo wants to ask for a password, but nohup disconnects the process from the controlling terminal.

Comment: so what I should do? `sudo nohup ./script &`?

Comment: try `sudo sh -c 'nohup ./script &'`. You don't want to put `sudo` in background when it asks for password.

Comment: You might also want to look at [sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) - bypasses the password for specially configured users

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why my question was closed, though. Oh well...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers, if a background process started with `nohup` tries to read from or write to the terminal, it is put into the "Stopped" state. The `sudo` process that you're executing tries to read your password from the terminal, so the process is stopped (for some reason, the reading seems to be triggered when Enter is pressed).

So, to avoid this, you ned to make sure to enter your password and become root before `nohup` is executed. For example, like this:

```sh
sudo bash -c 'nohup ./myScript.sh arg1 &'
```

Comment: My script does not need sudo but using bash -c worked for me, otherwise nohup always stopped after hitting enter

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo nohup ./script
```

After answering the password prompt, type <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> to suspend it, and `bg` to put it into the background.

This is especially helpful if you are half-way through running a long process when you decide it needs to be run in the background.

Comment: You mean `bg` to put it in the background

Answer (score 1):

One option here is use the *screen* utility.  Start screen, run your script, detach using CTRL+A, D. Later, log back in, reconnect to the process by running screen again.